# If value in column A is not null then insert specific string in column B. Python / Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, data-cleaning

I have a df and I want to insert a specific string (in this case "foo_bar") in column B when column A is not NULL.

```
A    B
foo  bar
foo  foo
NaN  NaN    
foo  bar
NaN  NaN
```

The ideal results would look like this.

```
A    B
foo  bar
foo  foo
NaN  foo_bar    
foo  bar
NaN  foo_bar
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
df['B']=np.where(df.A.isna(), 'foo_bar',df.B)
```

Comment: when column A is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `df.loc[df.A.isnull(), 'B'] = "foo_bar"`

This selects all rows where A is NaN, then select column B, and set the value to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['A'].notna(), 'B'] = 'foo_bar'
```